# Error "unknown delivery tag" occurs when i try ack messages to RabbitMQ using pika (python)

Tags: python, message-queue, rabbitmq, pika

I want process messages in few threads but i'm getting error during execute this code:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import pika
import sys
from pika.adapters.blocking_connection import BlockingConnection
from pika import connection, credentials
import time
import threading
import random
from pika.adapters.select_connection import SelectConnection
from pika.connection import Connection
import traceback


def doWork(body, args, channel):


    r = random.random()
    time.sleep(r * 10)
    try:        
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=args.delivery_tag)

    except :
        traceback.print_exc()


auth = credentials.PlainCredentials(username="guest", password="guest")
params = connection.ConnectionParameters(host="localhost", credentials=auth)
conn = BlockingConnection(params)
channel = conn.channel()


while True:

    time.sleep(0.03)    
    try:

        method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue="test_queue")
        if method_frame.NAME == 'Basic.GetEmpty':
            continue        

        t = threading.Thread(target=doWork, args=[body, method_frame, channel])
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    except Exception, e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        continue
```

Error desctiption:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\work\projects\mq\start.py", line 43, in 
    method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue="test_queue")
  File "C:\work\projects\mq\libs\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 318, in basic_get
    self.basic_get_(self, self._on_basic_get, ticket, queue, no_ack)
  File "C:\work\projects\mq\libs\pika\channel.py", line 469, in basic_get
    no_ack=no_ack))
  File "C:\work\projects\mq\libs\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 244, in send_method
    self.connection.process_data_events()
  File "C:\work\projects\mq\libs\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 94, in process_data_events
    self._handle_read()
  File "C:\work\projects\mq\libs\pika\adapters\base_connection.py", line 162, in _handle_read
    self._on_data_available(data)
  File "C:\work\projects\mq\libs\pika\connection.py", line 589, in _on_data_available
    frame)                 # Args
  File "C:\work\projects\mq\libs\pika\callback.py", line 124, in process
    callback(*args, **keywords)
  File "C:\work\projects\mq\libs\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 269, in _on_remote_close
    frame.method.reply_text)
AMQPChannelError: (406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 204')
```

Versions: pika 0.9.5, rabbitMQ 2.6.1

Comment: Yesterday i tried to use py-amqplib library instead pika. It worked fine. Likely there is a problem in pika library.

Comment: If you want to share your code across multiple threads you should use a thread safe library like rabbitpy or amqp-storm. Not sure if py-amqplib is threadsafe. https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm

Answer (score 48):

The problem probably is that you're setting `no_ack=True` like this:

```
consumer_tag = channel.basic_consume(
    message_delivery_event,
    no_ack=True,
    queue=queue,
)
```

And then acknowledging the messages:

```
channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=args.delivery_tag)
```

You have to chose if you want to acknowledge or not and set the correct consume parameter.

Comment: The root cause for my code is sync issue and config issue. I have a simple wrap to create rabbitmq consumer. When consume a temp queue (channel.queueDeclare("", false, true, true, args).getQueue()), the nextDelivery need to be protected using sync in multi-thread env. That means, if you get a message, you need to ack it before consume any other message. Otherwise, when call the ack, it will throw an exception and keep throw exception when consume...

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was having, thanks very much.

Comment: I was getting this error after a poor merge where a message was getting acked twice with the same delivery tag

Answer (score 14):

For me, it was just that I told the queue I wasn't going to ack, then I acked.

E.g. **WRONG**:

```
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=queue_name, no_ack=True)
```

and then in my callback:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
  # do stuff
  ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)
```

**RIGHT**:

```
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=queue_name, no_ack=False)
```

**Bottom line**: If you want to manually ack, set no_ack=False.

From the docs:

> no_ack:
>   (bool)
>   if set to True, automatic acknowledgement mode will be used (see http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)

Comment: Thank you. This was really useful. The problem I see is that that parameter name (no_ack, or noAck in .net) is kind of confusing. I feel like it should just be called "ack", and if you pass true it will acknowledge the message.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug with your code. You share a channel across threads. This is not supported by pika (see [FAQ](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html)). You have 2 options:

1. Define the `no_ack=True` flag in `basic_get(...)` and do not use the channel object in thread's function `doWork(...)`
2. If you need to ACK message only after you have finished your work, then let the main thread (the `while True:` loop) handle the message ack (and not the worker thread). Below is a modified version of your code that does that.

   ```
   from __future__ import with_statement
   import pika
   import sys
   from pika.adapters.blocking_connection import BlockingConnection
   from pika import connection, credentials
   import time
   import threading
   import random
   from pika.adapters.select_connection import SelectConnection
   from pika.connection import Connection
   import traceback
   from Queue import Queue, Empty

   def doWork(body, args, channel, ack_queue):
       time.sleep(random.random())
       ack_queue.put(args.delivery_tag)

   def doAck(channel):
       while True:
           try:
               r = ack_queue.get_nowait()
           except Empty:
               r = None
           if r is None:
               break
           try:
               channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=r)
           except:
               traceback.print_exc()

   auth = credentials.PlainCredentials(username="guest", password="guest")
   params = connection.ConnectionParameters(host="localhost", credentials=auth)
   conn = BlockingConnection(params)
   channel = conn.channel()
   # Create a queue for the messages that should be ACKed by main thread
   ack_queue = Queue()

   while True:
       time.sleep(0.03)    
       try:
           doAck(channel)
           method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue="test_queue")
           if method_frame.NAME == 'Basic.GetEmpty':
               continue        
           t = threading.Thread(target=doWork, args=[body, method_frame, channel, ack_queue])
           t.setDaemon(True)
           t.start()
       except Exception, e:
           traceback.print_exc()
           continue
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a fix, but I can verify that it occurs using the BlockingConnection
 adapter.

It consistently occurs when acknowledging or rejecting a message that is being redelivered in response to a channel.basic_recover()

pika 0.9.5, rabbitMQ 2.2.0, python 2.7, and Erlang R14B01

The workaround I have in place is to always specify deliver_tag=0

I suspect that this only works if the message you are acking/nacking is the last one you've read (in stream). The library I'm writing abstracts the message in such a way that each one can be acknowledged independently, which breaks with this solution.

Can anyone confirm if this has been fixed or acknowledged by anyone on the pika team yet ? Or, could it be it an issue with RabbitMQ ?

Comment: I am seeing this error with node-amqp, so it must be an issue with RabbitMQ (version 3.0.2-1).

Answer (score 1):

You might also be encountering this error if you are trying to acknowledge a message on a different channel from which it was created. This might happen if you are closing or recreating channels.

From the docs: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

> > Another scenario in which the broker will complain about an "unknown delivery tag" is when an acknowledgement, whether positive or negative, is attempted on a channel different from that on which the delivery was received on. Deliveries must be acknowledged on the same channel.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing [RabbitMQ - upgraded to a new version and got a lot of "PRECONDITION_FAILED unknown delivery tag 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075694/rabbitmq-upgraded-to-a-new-version-and-got-a-lot-of-precondition-failed-unkno)

I changed my basic-consume to look like this:

```
    consumer_tag = channel.basic_consume(
        message_delivery_event,
        no_ack=True,
        queue=queue,
    )
```

This had the effect of causing the described error on initial (not redelivered) acknowledgements when the message's delivery tag was specified. The delivery was extracted from the message delivery's method structure.

Using

```
    channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=0)
```

suppresses the error in this case, too

Looking at http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2011-July/013664.html makes it seem as though it may be an issue in RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is generated because you have set the { noack: true }, but still trying to send acknowledgement.