# How to do a nack in Python

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq

I tried to use these functions:
- basic_nack
- basic_reject
but I couldn't do it

I want an example of the nack in python using pika with one of these functions:
- basic_nack
- basic_reject

```
 def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
     ch.basic_reject(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag) 

return pika.exceptions.ChannelClosed: (406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1')
```

Comment: It's best if you share a complete, working code sample that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the `pika` documentation the message rejection can be done like this:

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
channel = connection.channel()

for method_frame, properties, body in channel.consume('test'):
    channel.basic_reject(method_frame.delivery_tag)
```

Note that you need to pass `delivery_tag` value from `method_frame` object, which specifies which message is being rejected.

`basic_reject()` method also accepts additional argument `requeue`, which is by default `True`.

Comment: I doing using a callback:

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
              ch.basic_reject(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

return pika.exceptions.ChannelClosed: (406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1')

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392478/error-unknown-delivery-tag-occurs-when-i-try-ack-messages-to-rabbitmq-using-pi
Make sure that `no_ack` argument is set to `False` in `basic_consume()`.